# How to create Firebase user without setting off authentication handler

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

When a new user creates an account, the function that creates the account sets off the authentication handler before the user and their profile picture can be completely written to Firebase Storage and Firebase Firestore. The handler navigates the app to another page where the viewDidLoad begins to fetch a feed based on Firestore information – but the user isn't written at that point.

```
 func didSignUp() {
    // Check the that the fields are not empty
    guard let name = nameField.text, !name.isEmpty else { return }
    guard let email = emailField.text, !email.isEmpty else { return }
    guard let password = passwordField.text, !password.isEmpty else { return }
    guard let image = imageView.image else { return }


    // If successful thus far, create a user
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

        //  If there is no error creating a user
        if error == nil {

            // Reset the input fields
            self.nameField.text = nil
            self.emailField.text = nil
            self.passwordField.text = nil
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "New User")


            // Upload the profile image to Firebase Storage
            self.uploadProfileImage(image, completion: { (url) in

                // Check to see if url is returned
                if url == nil {
                    print("Unable to upload profile image")
                }

                // Try to set the user's displayName and photoURL with a changeRequest
                let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                changeRequest?.displayName = name
                changeRequest?.photoURL = url
                changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in

                    // If there is an error, alert user
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error commiting change request: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }

                    // Once change request has succeeded, save profile to Firebase Firestore
                    self.saveProfile(name: name, photoURL: url!) { success in

                        if !success {
                            print("Failed to save user to Firestore")
                        } else {
                            self.navigateUserToHomePage()
                        }
                    }
                })

            })
        } else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error Creating Account", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to use Grand Central Dispatch to run some of the code asynchronously?

edit: I've uploaded the Firebase Functions

```
// Upload image data to Firebase Storage and return a URL of image if successful
func uploadProfileImage(_ image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL?) ->()) {

    // Create reference to the profile pictures and save as uid.jpg
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_pictures/\(uid).jpg")

    // Compress UIImage to jpegData
    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }

    // Create the file metadata
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    // Upload the image and metadata to the object profile_pictures/uid.jpg
    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in

        // Check for errors in uploading data to Firebase Storage
        guard metadata != nil, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        // Get access to the the download URL after upload
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

            // Check for errors in accessing download URL
            guard let downloadURL = url else {
                print("Couln't get profile image url")
                return
            }

            // Return download URL of uploaded image
            completion(downloadURL)
        })
    }
}

// Save user data to Firebase Firestore
func saveProfile(name: String, photoURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    // Create data to save as a dictionary of [String: Any]
    let userToSave: [String: Any] =  [Constants.UserKeys.uid: uid,
                                      Constants.UserKeys.name: name,
                                      Constants.UserKeys.photoURL: photoURL.absoluteString]

    // Create a document reference for Firestore
    docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid)

    // Save data to Firestore reference
    docRef.setData(userToSave) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error saving to Firestore: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        }
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at this quickly, the closures seem to be correct. Are you using OnAuthStateChanged() anywhere in the code? Put a breakpoint before `navigateUserToHomePage()` and log the user information to make sure it's actually there. There could be something else going on.

Comment: I put breakpoints and it seems like the createUser function works fine and the uploadProfileImage function does too. I double checked with the Firebase console each time I tried to make a new user and the users were both authenticated and had their images stored in Storage. However, they were never written to Firestore.

Comment: Where in the code are you writing to Cloud Firestore?

Comment: I've edited the post to show the saveProfile function, where the user's information is set to Firestore.

Comment: I tested the code you've provided and it works for me, but perhaps you could include the `uploadProfileImage()` function as well because I just made a simple function that has a url in its completion handler. Also, what are your rules for Cloud Firestore?

Comment: I've found a workaround where I just do the navigation that the authentication handler did at the END of the didSignUp function – however this is noticeably slower as it hangs on the signup page longer than before. 

My Firestore rules are simple: allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;